# How can I use where clause in the joined tables in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS with Laravel 5.
I have several models and they need to be joined.

I have 'PaymentData' model and 'AppsData' model. They both have 'mem_id' column and I want to get the 'app_process' column's values from 'AppsData' model based on the 'PaymentData' model's data.

What I tried below causes this error message.

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'app_process' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `BYAPPS_apps_payment_data` where `pay_type` != 1 and `amount` = 0 and `app_process` != 8)" on line 664 of /home/ljw/public_html/byapps_cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php

**PaymentData model**

```php
class PaymentData extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    public $table = 'BYAPPS_apps_payment_data';

    public $rules = [
    ];

    public $hasOne = [
      'joins' => [
        'Jiwon\Byapps\Models\AppsData',
        'key' => 'mem_id',
        'otherKey' => 'mem_id'
      ]
    ];
}
```

**AppsData model**

```php
class AppsData extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    public $table = 'BYAPPS_apps_data';

    public $rules = [
    ];
}
```

**what I tried in home.htm**

```php
use Jiwon\Byapps\Models\AppsData;
use Jiwon\Byapps\Models\PaymentData;

function onGetAppChartData()
{

  $this['appsFree'] = PaymentData::where('pay_type', '!=', '1')
                      ->where('amount', '=', '0')
                      ->where('app_process', '!=', '8')
                      ->count();
}
```

What did I wrong here? Please, someone help me...!_!

Comment: it seems that 'app_process' column not present in  BYAPPS_apps_payment_data  table. Run select query from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yep, 'app_process' column doesn't exist in BYAPPS_apps_payment_data table. It's in 'BYAPPS_apps_data' table. That's the point. I want to join the two tables and get the 'app_process' values but failed. !_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with writing a custom query like this:

```
$this['appsFree'] =   \DB::table('BYAPPS_apps_payment_data as p')
            ->join('BYAPPS_apps_data as a', 'a.mem_id', '=', 'p.mem_id')
            ->where('p.pay_type', '!=', '1')
            ->where('p.amount', '=', '0')
            ->where('p.app_process', '!=', '8')
            ->count();
```

Comment: I've written similar to this, but I thought this isn't the right way. What I made two tables joined in the models has nothing to do in here? Aren't they already joined?

Comment: No this is not how it works. refer this article https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many